# Get a <canvas> element to fill remaining height in a parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a canvas, I want to show it under a piece of text. The parent div that contains both the text and the canvas has an explicit height of 200px. I want the canvas to just fill in whatever height is left over below the text div, something like:

```
----------------------------
|  label div               |
----------------------------
|                          |
|  canvas                  |  entire height of parent
|  fill in rest of height  |  div should be 200px.
|  (height = 100%)         |
|                          |
----------------------------
```

This is what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         html, body {
           margin: 0px;
           padding: 0px;
         }
         canvas {
           width:50px;
           height:100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 200, 0); width:100%; height: 200px;">
         <div>hello</div>
         <canvas style="background-color: rgb(0,255,128);">
         </canvas>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

But notice how the canvas element spills over the bottom of the parent div:

[image]

Is there a way to just get the canvas to fill the remaining space without spilling out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a label class for the div above the container and give it a height percent and set the canvas to the remaining height. I've done an example with your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         html, body {
           margin: 0px;
           padding: 0px;
         }
         canvas {
           width:50px;
           height:90%;
         }
         .label {
        height: 10%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 200, 0); width:100%; height: 200px;">
         <div class="label">hello</div>
         <canvas style="background-color: rgb(0,255,128);">
         </canvas>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense - but what if I don't know the height that the label div will be roughly? Let's say I need to add an unknown number of child divs to it - is there no way to let it grow to whatever height it needs to be, and just have the canvas element fill whatever space is leftover? Thanks

Comment: You could use JavaScript. Look into JQuery. You could use the .css() method to get the height of the parent div, subtract out the height of the children and then use that to set the height of the canvas. It's more work, but quite flexible. [JQuery .css() page](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
 ... 
 <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 200, 0); width:100%; height: 200px; overflow: hidden">
 ...
```

Notice the added css rule overflow:hidden

Here is the full usage documentation for the css rule overflow
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html